# Remember multiple dropbox PHP variables

Tags: post, cookies, drop-down-menu, get

I need to create sort of a flter for videos. one dropbox selects number of  views and the other category. With the help of the good people on this website I managed to create the droplists but I have no idea how to make them "remember" the data from both - when a value is selected from one droplist the other droplist resets. How do i get around that?

here is the code:

```
<?php 
$views = (int) $_GET['views'];
$countries = "US";
$category =$_GET['category']; ?>
<div id="views">

<p>
View videos with
  <form name="views" method="GET" action="random.php">
        <select name='views' onChange='document.views.submit()'>
            <? $views_options = array (0, 50, 100, 500, 5000, 35000, 75000, 125000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 1000000, 3000000, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000);

foreach($views_options as $number_of_views) {
   echo '<option value="' . $number_of_views . '"' . ($_GET['views']==$number_of_views ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . number_format($number_of_views) . '</option>';
}
?>
    </select>
        </form>
  <p>views or more
  </p>

</div>

<div id="category">

<p>
Category:
  <form name="category" method="GET" action="random.php">
        <select name='category' onChange='document.category.submit()'>
            <? $category_options = array ("All", "Games", "Film", "Animals", "Travel", "Sports", "Education", "News", "Shows", "People", "Technology", "Comedy", "Entertainment", "Music", "Howto", "Autos", "Nonprofit");

foreach($category_options as $category_select) {
   echo '<option value="' . $category_select . '"' . ($_GET['category']==$category_select ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $category_select . '</option>';
}?>
    </select>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need two separate forms for this.

Merge both forms into one, so it should work:

```
<?php 
$views = (int) $_GET['views'];
$countries = "US";
$category =$_GET['category']; ?>
<div id="views">

<p>
View videos with
  <form name="views" method="GET" action="random.php">
        <select name='views' onChange='document.views.submit()'>
            <? $views_options = array (0, 50, 100, 500, 5000, 35000, 75000, 125000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 1000000, 3000000, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000);

foreach($views_options as $number_of_views) {
   echo '<option value="' . $number_of_views . '"' . ($_GET['views']==$number_of_views ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . number_format($number_of_views) . '</option>';
}
?>
    </select>
  <p>views or more
  </p>

</div>

<div id="category">

<p>
Category:
        <select name='category' onChange='document.views.submit()'>
            <? $category_options = array ("All", "Games", "Film", "Animals", "Travel", "Sports", "Education", "News", "Shows", "People", "Technology", "Comedy", "Entertainment", "Music", "Howto", "Autos", "Nonprofit");

foreach($category_options as $category_select) {
   echo '<option value="' . $category_select . '"' . ($_GET['category']==$category_select ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $category_select . '</option>';
}?>
    </select>
        </form>
```

Because you had used two forms only one of the dropdowns get submitted (e.g. you submit category, the dropdown "views" will be empty (you are using GET Method, you will see this in your URL)).

If you really need this separate two forms, you will have to save your variables into a PHP Session.

Comment: thanks, works great. Can you please tell me one more thing though. I am also planing to add a check box form to filter countries and it will have a submit button because i want to be able to check multiple values before submiting. Also i want the drop down lists to retain their auto submit feature. Is it possible to accompish something like this without using sessions?

Comment: Sure. Just add them to the form you already have. The bad point here is, that the check boxes will be submitted too, if you change a dropdown

Comment: thats not a big issue. thanks again for taking the time to help out a noob